# windows10の環境で、Dockerで、python3.8を起動しようとしましたが、エラーが発生してしまいます。

Tags: windows, docker

Windows PowerShellの環境下で、下記コマンドを実行しましたが、エラーが発生してしまいます。
処置方法について、ご教示願います。

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker run --name python38a -i -t python:3.8 /bin/bash
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: container e76352163bfea45b641101aa1c06002187c151bec4622cb5bcc47e63f48e2a12 encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"/bin/bash","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\","Environment":{"PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256":"421ac1d44c0cf9730a088e337867d974b91bdce4ea2636099275071878cc189e","PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL":"https://github.com/pypa/get-pip/raw/d59197a3c169cef378a22428a3fa99d33e080a5d/get-pip.py","PYTHON_PIP_VERSION":"20.0.2","PYTHON_RELEASE":"3.8.2","PYTHON_VERSION":"3.8.2"},"EmulateConsole":true,"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[49,120]}.
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker Desktop for Windowsには、[LinuxコンテナとWindowsコンテナを動かす機能](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers)があります。

> CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

というエラーメッセージからWindowsコンテナモードになっていると推測されます。そしてWindowsには`/bin/bash`が存在しないというエラーが発生しています。

いくつか質問を繰り返されていますが、根本的な問題としてLinux / Windowsどちらのコンテナを動かしたいのかを決定する必要があります。その上で、Webサイトや各種ドキュメントを参照する際、どちらのモードについて記述されたものかを確認するようにしてください。